# Ad hoc or distribute to app store for beta testing? Test flight

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

I need to deliver my app for beta testing but I am unclear to which provisional profile I should use, distribution ad hoc or distribution app store?

Thanks

Answer (score 22):

Apps for TestFlight beta testing should be regular distribution builds. You are actually submitting the app to the AppStore and it also gets reviewed.

It makes sense because you can invite external users (up to 1000 users) to test your app without having any information about their devices. With ad-hoc builds you must have all devices registered in your dev center account (up to 100 users).

See more info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8).

Comment: Ah thanks, I thought that was the case. What is the point of created a distributed app with ad-hoc?

Comment: Will it also take a long time to get it submitted and reviewed for a beta?

Comment: With ad-hoc you don't need to go through any submission or review process so you can use it to deliver beta versions for clients for example or to share a very preliminary version with friends, colleagues, etc. ad-hoc also provides a way to test problematic versions that you've already released (you re-sign your archive with an ad-hoc provision).

Comment: How long is the review process, is it long? I will be doing beta testing next week, should I do ad-hoc?

Comment: It's supposed to be shorter than regular review times, but you can never know for sure. I think if you're doing a beta next week then it should to be okay.

Comment: If I create the app non-ad hoc, how does apple differentiate whether it is for beta or official app store release? Since they both published using the same provisional profile.

Comment: You specify in the entitlements that it's for beta. All info is in the guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH35